# Using Host Group as Variable in Ansible Task

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I'm working on putting together a playbook that will deploy local facts scripts to various groups in my Ansible inventory, and I would to be able to utilize the group name being worked on as a variable in the tasks themselves.  Assume for this example that I have the traditional Ansible roles directory structure on my Ansible machine, and I have subdirectories under the "files" directory called "apache", "web", and "db".  I'll now illustrate by example, ...

```
---
- hosts: apache:web:db

  tasks:
  - name: Set facts for facts directories
    set_fact:
      facts_dir_local: "files/{{ group_name }}"
      facts_dir_remote: "/etc/ansible/facts.d"

   - name: Deploy local facts
     copy:
       src: "{{ item }}"
       dest: "{{ facts_dir_remote }}"
       owner: ansible
       group: ansible
       mode: 0750
     with_fileglob:
      - "{{ facts_dir_local }}/*.fact"
```

The goal is to have `{{ group_name }}` above take on the value of "apache" for the hosts in the apache group, "web" for the hosts in the web group, and "db" for the hosts in the db group.  This way I don't have to copy and paste this task and assign custom variables for each group.  Any suggestions for how to accomplish this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So, what kinda problem you're having? Your tasks are not working at all or not working as you wish?

Comment: @KelsonSilva I would just like {{ group_name }} to take on the value of the group that's undergoing execution of the playbook.  For instance if it's currently working on all nodes in my "db" group, I want {{ group_name }} to be the string "db"

Comment: @KelsonSilva I thought it would be handy to have different sub-directories in my files directory so that i can just say "copy all .fact files from this directory to that directory", so I thought it'd be a good idea to organize these directories and name them after group names in my inventory (i.e. "db", "web", "apache"); for example under files/facts we'll have subdirectories files/facts/db, files/facts/web, and files/facts/apache and under those subdirectories we'll have the actual .fact files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there is no `group_name` variable in ansible, there is a `group_names` (plural). That is because any host may be part of one or more groups.

It is described in the [official documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html) as

> **group_names**
> List of groups the current host is part of

In the most common case each host would only be part of one group and so you could simply say `group_names[0]` to get what you want.

TLDR;

Use `group_names[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use group variables to achieve this, either specified in the inventory file or in separate `group_vars/<group>` files - see https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html

Note though that these group variables are squashed into host variables when you run the playbook. Hosts that are listed in multiple groups will end up with variables based on a precedence order